# How can I add SDK 6.1 on livecode 5.5.3?

Tags: xcode, sdk, livecode

I need to add SDK 6.1 with my current version on Livecode 5.5.3. I've tried adding it in preferences-> Mobile Support but it will just say "the chosen folder is not a valid IOS SDK". Are these version of livecode and xcode compatible? I can add xcode 4.5.2 but can't add xcode 4.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems adding Xcode 4.6.2 to LiveCode 5.5.4 so maybe you need to upgrade your LiveCode.

Note: if you want to submit to the app store you need to upgrade to 5.5.5

Comment: Yes I have no problem adding xcode 4.6.2 on livecode 5.5.4 but I adding xcode 4.6.2 on livecode 5.5.3 doesn't work. Anyway this is now working when we upgraded to Livecode 5.5.5. Thanks.